# ECS with ubuntu container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I have seen some documents in the AWS stating we can use ubuntu instead of default amazon instances. But my question, let's say i created the ubuntu machine and installed the ecs agents with pointing the ECS cluster and in the cluster the ubuntu machine appears - a happy flow. But tomorrow if i need to do a horizontal scaling, how it will do ? do we need to do manually ?

Comment: You would have an autoscaling group create your Ubuntu instance and run the ECS setup via a user data script.

Comment: that would be difficult rght ? each user data need to have for different clusters for the ecs agent configuraiton ?

Comment: you typically create 1 AutoScaling Group per ECS cluster, and the userdata injects the cluster name into the config (there's a sample AWS doc on it somewhere).  You can then run multiple ECS Services on each cluster